# jQuery access object attribute by index

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{"error":true,"variable":{"v_f1_email":["error-mail","mail"]}}
```

I am trying to access 'error-mail' and 'mail' like this:

```
var JSD = JSON.parse(data);

if (JSD.error == true) {
    $(JSD.variable).each(function(index, el) {
        var error = el[0];
        var type = el[0];
        console.log(error + type);
    })
```

Unfortunately the vars `error` and `type` are returning `undefined`. Where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: aren't you supposed to go one level deeper, i.e. first get to `v_f1_email`...?

Comment: If you only have one then `var errormsg = JSD.variable.v_f1_email; console.log(errormsg[0],errormsg[1])`

Comment: Why are you setting `error` and `type` to the same element?

Comment: You are using the *wrong* `each` method.  jQuery has two: [one](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is for jQuery objects, the [other](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is for arrays/objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

Note: I renamed the vars in the each to show it is not an indexed array but key/value

```js
// var JSD = JSON.parse(data); // version to use in your page
var JSD = {"error":true,"variable":{"v_f1_email":["error-mail","mail"]}};
if (JSD.error) {
   $.each(JSD.variable,function(fieldName,errorArr) {
     $("#error").append(fieldName+": error:"+errorArr[0]+", type:"+errorArr[1]); 
   });   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error"></div>
```